# ubuntu 16.04 cloud formation template

Tags: templates, ubuntu-16.04, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to setup a cloud formation template to deploy ubuntu 16.04. The template deploys fine and I can SSH to the server., but the extra packages I defined, like apache and php modules will not install. I can't seem to figure out why that is? I looked at several code sniplets online, but can't seem to get it to work properly. Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong here?

The Code:

```
{
"Description" : "Staging single instance",
"Outputs": {
    "InstanceID": {
        "Description": "The WWW instance id",
        "Value": { "Ref": "StageInstance" }
    }
},
"Parameters": {
    "AMI": {
        "Description": "The Amazon Ubuntu AMI",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "ami-996372fd"
    },
    "EBSVolumeSize": {
        "Description": "The size of the EBS volume for the transcoder",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "20"
    },
    "InstanceType": {
        "AllowedValues": [
            "t2.micro",
            "t2.small",
            "t2.medium",
            "t2.large",
            "c4.large",
            "c4.xlarge",
            "c4.2xlarge",
            "c4.4xlarge",
            "c4.8xlarge"
        ],
        "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type",
        "Default": "t2.micro",
        "Description": "EC2 instance type",
        "Type": "String"
    },
    "KeyName": {
        "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to NAT instances.",
                    "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
                    "ConstraintDescription" : "Must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."        },
    "Subnet": {
        "Description": "The subnet to place the instance in...",
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id",
        "ConstraintDescription" : "Must be a valid Subnet."
    },
    "VPC": {
        "Description": "The VPC to deploy to...",
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
        "ConstraintDescription" : "Must be a valid VPC."
    }
},
"Resources": {
    "StageSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
            "GroupDescription": "Allow SSH, HTTP, and HTTPS access",
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "22",
                    "ToPort": "22",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "80",
                    "ToPort": "80",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "443",
                    "ToPort": "443",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "StageInstance": {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
            "config": {
                "packages": {
                    "apt": {
                    "awscli": [ ],
                    "apache2": [ ],
                    "php7.0": [ ], 
                    "libapache2-mod-php7.0": [ ], 
                    "php7.0-cli": [ ], 
                    "php7.0-common": [ ], 
                    "php7.0-mbstring": [ ], 
                    "php7.0-gd": [ ], 
                    "php7.0-intl": [ ], 
                    "php7.0-xml": [ ], 
                    "php7.0-mysql": [ ], 
                    "php7.0-mcrypt": [ ], 
                    "php7.0-zip": [ ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
        "Properties": {
            "BlockDeviceMappings" : [{
                "DeviceName" : "/dev/sda1",
                "Ebs" : {"VolumeSize" : {"Ref" : "EBSVolumeSize"}}
            }],
            "SecurityGroupIds": [{"Ref": "StageSecurityGroup"}],
            "KeyName": {"Ref": "KeyName" },
            "ImageId": {"Ref": "AMI"},
            "SubnetId": {"Ref": "Subnet"},
            "InstanceType": {"Ref": "InstanceType"},
            "Tags": [
                {"Key" : "Name", "Value" : "Ldn_Svr_Stage_Web"}
            ],
             "UserData": {
     "Fn::Base64": {
       "Fn::Join": [
         "",
         [
           "#!/bin/bash -x\n",
           "apt-get update\n",
           "apt-get install -y python-pip\n",
           "pip install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz\n",
           "cfn-init -v –resource StageInstance",
           " –stack ",
           {
             "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
           },
           " –region ",
           {
             "Ref": "AWS::Region"
           },
           "\n",
           "cfn-signal -e $? –resource StageInstance",
           " –stack ",
           {
             "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
           },
           " –region ",
           {
             "Ref": "AWS::Region"
           },
           "\n"
         ]
       ]
     }
   }
 }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the working code for a simple example....

```
{
    "Description": "stack descripton.....",
    "Parameters": {
        "AMI": {
            "Default": "ami-996372fd",
            "Description": "The Amazon Ubuntu AMI",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "EBSVolumeSize": {
            "Default": "20",
            "Description": "The size of the EBS volume",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "InstanceName": {
            "Default": "My instance name",
            "Description": "EC2 Instance Name",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "InstanceType": {
            "AllowedValues": [
                "t2.micro",
                "t2.small",
                "t2.medium",
                "t2.large",
                "c4.large",
                "c4.xlarge",
                "c4.2xlarge",
                "c4.4xlarge",
                "c4.8xlarge"
            ],
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type",
            "Default": "t2.micro",
            "Description": "EC2 instance type",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "KeyName": {
            "ConstraintDescription": "Must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.",
            "Description": "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to NAT instances.",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
        },
        "Subnet": {
            "ConstraintDescription": "Must be a valid Subnet.",
            "Description": "The subnet to place the instance in...",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id"
        },
        "VPC": {
            "ConstraintDescription": "Must be a valid VPC.",
            "Description": "The VPC to deploy to...",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "Instance": {
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                    "config": {
                        "packages": {
                            "apt": {
                                "awscli": [],
                                "ruby": [],
                                "unzip": []
                            }
                        },
                        "files": {
                        "/tmp/sample.conf": {
                            "content": {
                                "Fn::Join": [
                                    "",
                                    [
                                        "write a sample file to OS and give permissions....   \n"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            },
                            "mode": "000644",
                            "owner": "root",
                            "group": "root"
                          }

                        },
                        "commands": {
                            "01update_pkgs": {
                                "command": "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y"
                            },
                            "02next_command": {
                                "command": "echo the numbering here has to be in order... 01, 02, 03 and so on... last item is not comma'd"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "Properties": {
                "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                    {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                        "Ebs": {
                            "VolumeSize": {
                                "Ref": "EBSVolumeSize"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "ImageId": {
                    "Ref": "AMI"
                },
                "InstanceType": {
                    "Ref": "InstanceType"
                },
                "KeyName": {
                    "Ref": "KeyName"
                },
                "SecurityGroupIds": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "SecurityGroup"
                    }
                ],
                "SubnetId": {
                    "Ref": "Subnet"
                },
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": {
                            "Ref": "InstanceName"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "UserData": {
                    "Fn::Base64": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                                "apt-get install -y python-setuptools\n",
                                "mkdir -p /opt/aws/bin\n",
                                "wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz\n",
                                "easy_install --script-dir /opt/aws/bin aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz\n",
                                " apt-get update\n",
                                "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init --region ",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                },
                                " -s ",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                                },
                                " -r Instance\n"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance"
            },
        "EIPAddress": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP"
        },
        "IPAssoc": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation",
            "Properties": {
                "InstanceId": {
                    "Ref": "Instance"
                },
                "EIP": {
                    "Ref": "EIPAddress"
                }
            }
        },
        "SecurityGroup": {
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": "Allow SSH, HTTP, and HTTPS access",
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                    {
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
                        "FromPort": "22",
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "ToPort": "22"
                    },
                    {
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
                        "FromPort": "443",
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "ToPort": "443"
                    }
                ],
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VPC"
                }
            },
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution will get the packages to install and run the commands, but it wont continue after a reboot.  Configuration of cfn-hup is missing as well as the call to cfn-signal to indicate the script worked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a apache.json file :

```
  {
    "Resources" :
    {
    "WebServer":{
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
         "Properties":{
         "ImageId" : "ami-9a7724c8",
         "KeyName" : "demo",
         "InstanceType":"t1.micro",
         "SecurityGroups" : [ "demo" ],
         "UserData" : {"Fn::Base64" : {"Fn::Join" : ["", [
           "#!/bin/bash\n",
           "# Launching Instance",
           "apt-get -y install apache2 \n",
           "apt-get -y install php php5-mysql \n"
            ] ] } }
        }
    }
 },
 "Outputs":{
    "WebsiteURL" : {
      "Value" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["http://", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [        
"WebServer", "PublicDnsName" ]}]] },
        "Description" : "URL for newly created  apache server "
    }
 }
}
```

Then create a cloud formation stack using this json file.

Kindly validate the json file before saving it.

Hope it will help !